# Adjacent sibling combinator (+) issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I'm using the **adjacent sibling combinator (+)** in my css. It appears to only work in Firefox but not Internet Explorer.
Below is the offending code snippet.

```
    .mycheckbox:checked + label {
      // Do something to the label when the checkbox is checked
    }
```

Comment: in what ie version do you test? It works on ie8+ according http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your edit:

`:checked` is not supported in IE8. It works in IE9.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked

---

Old answer:

The only likely reason is that your page is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Add a valid doctype as the very first line to trigger Standards Mode, in which the adjacent sibling combinator will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```